# Weird extra text after my file name in nerdtree {language}

Tags: plugin-nerdtree

[image]
I'm not sure if it is duplicated or not, I tried to find Google also in here but cannot find the correct answer.

I do not know why it shows `{language}` next to the file `languages.js`, as I use almost the same vimrc on my Ubuntu, and it does not show over there.

List of my plugins, in Vundle:

```
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'epmatsw/ag.vim'
Plugin 'mileszs/ack.vim'
Plugin 'ascenator/L9', {'name': 'newL9'}
Plugin 'drewtempelmeyer/palenight.vim'
Plugin 'rakr/vim-one'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
Plugin 'sangdth/vue-element-snippets'
Plugin 'sangdth/tapilu-snippets'
Plugin 'fatih/vim-go'
Plugin 'posva/vim-vue'
Plugin 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
Plugin 'leafgarland/typescript-vim'
Plugin 'flazz/vim-colorschemes'
Plugin 'editorconfig/editorconfig-vim'
Plugin 'w0rp/ale'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'tiagofumo/vim-nerdtree-syntax-highlight'
Plugin 'SirVer/ultisnips'
Plugin 'honza/vim-snippets'
Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
Plugin 'ryanoasis/vim-devicons'
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I found out. It sounds stupid but I created by myself.
I do not know when did I make it, but it is a bookmark in nerdtree. Press <kbd>B</kbd> to see the list and <kbd>D</kbd> to delete it.